# Should unanswered questions be closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

I have a question that was posted some time back that never got an answer. I actually do not need an answer anymore because I stumbled upon a work-around. Should I close this post or just leave it up for other users? If so, how do I close it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Post the answer yourself, then accept it.  Then other people can use your solution.

Comment: Agreed, even if it's just a work-around.  Some people might be able to use it, and others might be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Guys! I'll make sure to post it.

Comment: What if there are no answers and the post is out of date (e.g: dead links)?