# How should users handle unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, accept-rate

This question is similar but I don't have an answer to my question, *yet*: [Should unanswered questions be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91676/should-unanswered-questions-be-closed)

Should users leave unanswered questions open? Also, do many unanswered questions decrease a user's acceptance rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should users leave unanswered questions open?

Yes! Why do you think that an unanswered question should be closed/deleted if it is a constructive or a real question?

> How should users handle unanswered questions?

If you really want some attentions on your/others' questions you can start [a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties). Also try to make your question more clear and answerable.

> Also, do many unanswered questions decrease a user's acceptance rate?

Questions with no answers does not affect your accept rate. **Remember** there is a difference between [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) and [questions with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers). For more see [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16721/187824)

Answer (score 6):

There are incidents where rather unanswerable questions slide by without down votes or flags, some can even linger in that state for years. Stack Overflow can churn very quickly depending on the time of day; low velocity mediocre questions can fall into the proverbial abyss very quickly. If you feel like you've come across something old and unanswerable, or perhaps something that was just extremely localized, flag it for our attention and we'll take a look.

When people ask me how to get started with Stack Overflow, the first thing I show them is the unanswered question tab. While it is not a source of low hanging fruit, it's a great place for someone to jump in. If a question that was asked long ago remains relevant and *can* be answered, it can mean a nice shiny badge for someone that had the time and inclination to research it.

I don't think there's a blanket rule that can be followed, it broadly depends on the question. When contemplating nearly any action one could take on a question, quality is generally the first thing to consider.

Comment: I agree with checking out the unanswered questions tab. I've also started researching unanswered bounty questions as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Should users leave unanswered questions open?

A question shouldn't be closed just because it hasn't been answered, no.  It should only be closed if it *can't* be answered because the question doesn't provide enough information, is too vague, etc. (see the "Not a Real Question" close reason for specifics.

> Also, do many unanswered questions decrease a user's acceptance rate?

No, not that accept rate is that important anyway.