# After some time, should the OP be required to accept an answer or delete the unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Should people be required to either accept an answer or delete the question if it has been live for a certain period of time (say 1 month) without any traffic (i.e. comment or answer)?

Comment: What problem does forcing an accept solve/address?

Comment: Some questions are automatically deleted after 30 days; see [Auto-deleting old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Comment: Again, how's that a problem? What would having everyone at 100% accept rate solve/improve? Having bad/wrong answers accepted because people are forced to sounds like a really bad idea. Questions that don't have an accepted answer don't hurt anything, votes rate the content.

Comment: ***Closely*** related and just asked today: [How should users handle unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159964/how-should-users-handle-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Some problems got.resolved after a few releases of library/framework, taking more than one year...

Answer (score 13):

I disagree with this idea. We can't force OP to accept our/anyone's answer. It totally depends on OP whether to accept the answer or not. And why to delete a question if it is a real or a constructive question?

Comment: This furthers my accept-rate-should-just-go-away stance even more.

Comment: @TinyTimPost <jk>You're just saying that because yours is so low?</jk> I guess one could make a case for keeping it as a private field in the profile. But it should definitely be removed from the public.

Comment: @TinyTimPost I've given it [one last push](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)...

Answer (score 7):

No, this makes no sense. I've had a few questions receive an answer which doesn't actually answer the question correctly or for whatever other reason don't solve the problem.

Accepting that "answer" is actually worse than not accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One question may answered again in the future, also existing answers can be reference to what they try to this question - and maybe some of them work even if they not have been accepted.

Also there is the case that many users hit one two questions, and then disappear from the site and not accept the answer that they have get.

I disagree also with this idea.